# How to fix python ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, fiona, importerror

During import fiona, I am getting following error. Error is different from other user so I asked this question may be it is repeated.

```
import fiona

Traceback (most recent call last):
```

> File "D:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> File "D:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona__init__.py", line 79, in 
>       from fiona.collection import Collection, supported_drivers, vsi_path
>
> File "D:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> File "D:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 7, in 
>       from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
>
> File "D:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 309, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: I think Fiona (and Shapely) both require GDAL installed. Have you also installed this?

Comment: A tool often used at StackOverflow to find missing dependencies (dll's, etc.) is http://www.dependencywalker.com/. Maybe try this first to see which DLL is missing.

Comment: Seeing the QGIS import machinery at work tells me that you're trying to use a plugin that depends on Fiona, right? You really ought to spell this out in your question so that people don't have to do unnecessary detective work to help you. 

Joseph above is right, this is a case of the GDAL DLL not being found. Hopefully the developer of the plugin will see your question and help you out.

Comment: Yes. I already installed both GDAL.

Answer (score 5):

When you read [Python Package Index: Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona/1.4.8)

> Fiona requires Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4 and GDAL/OGR 1.8+. To build from a source distribution you will need a C compiler and GDAL and Python development headers and libraries (libgdal1-dev for Debian/Ubuntu, gdal-dev for CentOS/Fedora).

What does it mean ?

That Fiona is not a pure Python module and needs to be compiled from the C/C++ libraries of [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) and other [requirements](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/requirements.txt) installed.

As there is no native compiler on Windows:

> Windows Binary installers are available at [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fionahttp://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona) http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona and coming eventually to PyPI.

Therefore, you need to install:

1. first the [gdal (osgeo)](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) module of Christoph Gohlke
2. then his [Fiona](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona) version, compiled for the libraries of 1)

But, there is a problem since you are using the Python version of QGIS. There is already an `osgeo` module installed and used by QGIS (in D:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo). I am not on Windows, so I do not know if you can replace it with the Christoph Gohlke's version (try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) as  Kersten says)

But why install Fiona in the Python version of QGIS, while there is PyQGIS ? Fiona has been made to work in pure Python.

Comment: Gene, I too suspect that Fiona and QGIS can't be mixed on Windows due to the extra osgeo.gdal dependency. Would be nice if somebody conclusively answered this category of question because it comes up regularly.

Comment: This worked for me to get fiona working on windows. I did have to use --upgrade when installing gdal and fiona from step 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem running anaconda/spyder on a windows machine and it turned out to be an issue with a Microsoft patch that was not installed which is required by gdal.

I was not able to import gdal and fiona until I downloaded the correct patch (I am on a 64-bit windows 7 system and the x84 version would not work for me.  It was downloaded by my network admin, so I had to remove it and install the correct x64 version, so do be careful to get the correct version for your system.  After that I removed and re-installed gdal and fiona with pip.

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/cGhArND_2T8

Here is the link to the patch:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368